# IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying run the query, but return the error below:

`IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join pyspark`

Follow the part of query:

```
CASE
WHEN
MEIO IN ('CARTÃO A','CARTÃO ML','Cartão C') 
AND PGTO IN (SELECT PGTO FROM campanhas) 
THEN 'GH'
```

How to fix the error using subquery in pyspark?

Comment: convert it to a join and create a flag (say `pgto_flag`) for values that are in both tables

Comment: Can you write for me @samkart? Please